# Divide To Ids to get a new result

Tags: jquery, divide

I have 2 Ids **#totalcbm** and **#gross**, i want to divide both these values using jquery and to store the result in a new id **#result**.

How can i do this using jQuery.

Comment: rephrase your question and put more effort writing it and post what have you tried

Comment: What do you mean divide and what do they contain ?

Comment: they are div,textarea,input ,span or what?

Comment: @Sarfaraz By Divide, i mean they contain values like 24 and 65... i want to divide #totalcbm by #gross and to store the result in a new id #result..

Comment: @Somebody is in trouble: they are input field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var result = parseFloat(('#totalcbm').val()) / parseFloat(('#gross').val());
$('#result').val(result);
```

Comment: It gives 1 as result no matter what the values are...
btw, nice site

Answer (score 1):

This is damn simple if the divs contain a text.

```
var result = parseFloat($('#totalcbm').text()) / parseFloat($('#gross').text());
$('result').text(result);
```

If these are textboxes/textareas see this:

```
var result = parseFloat($('#totalcbm').val()) / parseFloat($('#gross').val());
$('result').val(result);
```

Please try to put your own efforts in such simple things.

Comment: If it is a text box/area, use `val()`. I have updated the answer :)